# Making a portion of a TreeViewItem wrap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a `TreeViewItem` that has multiple parts in it -- an icon, a header, and a piece of data.  I'm trying to get the last part to wrap without making everything wrap, and I'm having no luck.  Here's an illustration of the problem:

[image: This is not wrapping.]

I've tried a few things that I've found on Stack Overflow, with no luck.  There were three suggestions I found:

1. Put the item in a grid with a column with bound to the `TreeView`'s actual width.  This is implemented in the XAML below, but doesn't seem to help.
2. Disable horizontal scrolling on the `TreeView` with `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Disabled"`, which I also implemented in the XAML below.
3. Wrap what I need in a `WrapPanel`.  I tried this, but got poor results.  When I wrapped the whole `TreeViewItem` in one, I got wrapping that was hard to control (the whole item wraps, so all parts wrapped and it looked awful).  When I wrapped just the desired `TextBlock` in one, I got no results at all.  So I took it out.

Here's the template I have for the `TreeViewItem`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BasicPropertyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type json:JProperty}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Width="12"
                Height="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='Interior'}"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"
                BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text=": " />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Column="6"
                Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's an illustration of the layout, so you can see how the `TreeViewItem` is composed:

[image: TreeViewItem layout.]

Essentially, the gray part is the icon, the green parts are just spacers between items, the blue parts are header and a colon (essentially irrelevant to what this question is about), and the red part is the actual content.

It's the red part I want to wrap.

Here's the `TreeView` definition:

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="JsonRoot"
    Grid.Column="0"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}"
    Loaded="JsonRoot_Loaded"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />
```

I feel like I'm doing something simple wrong, but I'm not sure what.  Is there a way to accomplish this without just locking the `TextBlock` width to something arbitrary, like 200?

Comment: Do you use any custom TreeView or TreeViewItem control templates ?

Comment: I actually got wrapping to work but you have to change the default Tree templates a bit, and it's actually quite simple, and does not require any hardcoded Widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My investigation showed that TextBlock Wrap doesn't work with `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>`. So I changed last `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>` in DataTemplate to `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>`.

Unfortunately TreeViewItem (which is a default container for TreeView items) has `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>` in its Template and places our items there. I have tried to make a custom template with `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>` and it worked but code is really long. So I decided to compensate the effect by binding Grid width:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BasicPropertyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type json:JProperty}">
    <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=ActualWidth}" >
        <Grid Margin="0,0,20,0"> <!--right margin to compensate excessive width-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!--was Auto-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
            Width="12"
            Height="12"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='Interior'}"
            BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"
            BorderThickness="1" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text=": " />
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column="6"
            Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` is important element and should be set.

Comment: curious TreeViewItem template: another example of TextBlock wrap from [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868421/treeviewitem-with-stretch) works because there is `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` on `Border x:Name="Bd"`, so it again eliminates `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>`

Comment: That worked!  I had to tweak it a bit to my own circumstances (the margin had to be `0 0 80 0`) because the text would wrap just a tiny bit too late (resulting in some words at the end getting cut off before the wrap) but that generally did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the grid in DataTemplate with a DockPanel:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
        <Border Width="12"
                Height="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='Interior'}"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"
                BorderThickness="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock Text=": " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me.  I tried it (and copied your template exactly) but it still didn't do the trick.  Thanks though!