# How to prevent the TreeView's DataTemplate from causing the control to expand horizontally?

Tags: wpf, treeview

Very new to WPF.

```
            <TreeView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="DataTree" MinWidth="175" BorderThickness="0">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:DispatchTreeTerritoryItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientLocations}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:DispatchTreeClientLocationItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientName,StringFormat='({0}) '}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

The data in the `DispatchTreeClientlocationItem` properties (`ClientName` and `Address`), do not fit within the width of the treeview.  So when the items are created the treeview control expands itsself horizontally to allow all the tree node's text to be visible.

This is not desired behavior.  I would like it to behave like WinForms TreeView, where the text is just truncated at the edge of the control.  Is that possible in WPF?  And how?

**UPDATE**

Following @Funk's comment and the suggestion in the linked question my TreeView XAML now looks like:

```
<TreeView   x:Name="DataTree" Grid.Column="0"  MinWidth="175" BorderThickness="0"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

I've observed no change in the behavior.  When node text is too long to fit within the horizontal confines of the TreeView, the TreeView expands horizontally to display all the text.

Here's a couple screenshots to illustrate the problem.  When expanding a territory node, the child node's contents cause the TreeView to expand horizontally.

[image: collapsed treeview]  [image: expanded treeview]

Comment: You can disable expansion by setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the `TreeView`.
Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776693/making-a-portion-of-a-treeviewitem-wrap) post, taking it _one_ step further.

Comment: @Funk: following your suggestion produced no observable change.

Comment: @SamAxe, which container TreeView is located in? if it a Grid and columnDefinition has `Width="Auto"`, expanding is an expected behavior. try set MaxWidth or proportional width

Comment: @ASh: You are correct.  I had no idea it was the Grid Column causing this.  Thank you for that insight.  Changing the Column Definition Width from Auto to a fixed size made the problem go away.  If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `TreeView` is located in a `Grid` and `ColumnDefinition` has `Width="Auto"`, expanding is an expected behavior.

Try set MaxWidth (on ColumnDefinition or on TreeView), or proportional width `*` / fixed width (on ColumnDefinition)

Grid rows (RowDefinition) have similar behavior when their Height is set to Auto